# MySQL table update after in-table comparison

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Due to a faulty Wordpress/bbPress import, I have duplicate user records, ie "james@foo.com", ID 8 and "imported_james@foo.com", ID 104.

The imported posts have been allocated to ID 104. I would like to change them to 8, so that I can delete all the "imported_%" users.

Is there a query or a simple php script that allows me to perform this in one go?

```
SELECT  "from", ou.ID, "to", u.ID FROM wp_users u 
LEFT JOIN wp_users ou ON u.user_email=substring(ou.user_email,10) 
WHERE ou.ID IS NOT NULL
```

This shows me the old ones and the new ones side by side. But what do I need to do to update the post.author in wp_posts with the new value?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following script that did this in one go:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;

$sbs=$wpdb->query("select ou.ID old_id, u.ID new_id from wp_mmk_users u left join wp_mmk_users ou on u.user_email=substring(ou.user_email,10) where ou.ID IS NOT NULL", OBJECT);

foreach($sbs as $row) {

$wpdb->update('wp_mmk_posts', 
array( 'post_author' => $row->new_id),
array('post_author'=> $row->old_id),
array( '%d' ),array( '%d' ) 
);

echo "old: ".$row->old_id." new: ".$row->new_id."<br />";
}
?>
```

That did the trick. :)